# How do I stop content from being pushed outside of the screen when appending html to a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://codepen.io/bayleymauger/pen/BwWZjR 
How would I go about preventing the content from going outside the screen view when the twitch channel divs load into view. It pushes the twitch most of the twitch logo and above out of view and I can't for the life of me figure out how to go about fixing this. If anyone has any ideas and even better a solution then it would be a pleasure speaking to you and much appreciated.

```js
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
var usernames = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var api = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/';
// USERNAME LOOP
$.map(usernames, function(channel) {
  function makeURL(type, name) {
    return api + type + '/' + name;
  }
  // AJAX 1 START
  $.ajax({
    url: makeURL("streams", channel),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      let game,
        status;
      if (data.stream === null) {
        game = "Offline";
        status = "offline";
      } else if (data.stream === undefined) {
        game = "Account closed";
        status = "offline";
      } else {
        game = data.stream.game;
        status = "online";
      };

      // AJAX 2 START
      $.ajax({
        url: makeURL("channels", channel),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
          // LOGO
          var logo = data.logo != null ? data.logo : "images/twitch-favicon.png",

            // NAME
            name = data.display_name != null ? data.display_name : channel,

            // DESCRIPTION   
            description = status === "online" ? ": " + data.status : "";
          console.log(game + description);
          // HTML
          var html = '<div class="col s12 z-depth-1 hoverable channel ' + status + '"><img src="' + logo + '" alt="channel logo" class="responsive-img channel-pic left circle"><a href="' + data.url + '" target="_blank"><p class="blue-text"><strong>' + name + '</strong></p></a><p>' + game + description + '</p></div>';
          status === "online" ? $("#channels").prepend(html) : $("#channels").append(html);
          return false;
        } // 2 SUCCESS END
      }); // AJAX 2 END
    } // 1 SUCCESS END
  }); // AJAX 1 END
}); // MAP END
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #9c27b0;
  text-align: center:
}

#twitch-logo {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
  width: 7.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#channels {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.channel-pic {
  width: 4rem;
  margin: .4rem 0;
}

p {
  font-size: .7rem;
  margin: .4rem;
}

#channel_name {
  color: #42a5f5;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}

#app {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.channel {
  margin-top: .8rem
}

.online {
  background-color: #a5d6a7;
}

.offline {
  background-color: #ef9a9a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s10 m10 l6 center-align white z-depth-3" id="app">
      <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53d.png" alt="Twitch logo" class="responsive-img" id="twitch-logo"></a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">all</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn purple">online</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn purple">offline</a>
      <!-- CHANNELS START -->
      <div class="col s12" id="channels">

      </div>
      <!-- CHANNELS END -->
    </div>
    <!-- COL S6 -->
  </div>
  <!-- ROW -->
</div>
<!-- CONTAINER -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your remove the `height` property on the `html` and `body` selectors, the logo will not go out of view.

```
html, body {
    /*max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `height` and `max-height` for your `body` and `html` tags in CSS. (You have set CSS for them in the first line of your styles.)

Here is the [CodePen forked](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPrVGN).